# How to get values from text file and store it as a variable in batch script?

Tags: batch-file, variables, text-files, findstr

How can I get the specific value from text file and store it at a variable by using batch scripting?

Eg. (input.txt)

```
    ============================================================
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    ============================================================
    True
    True
    0000: 56 43 54 23 34 25 33 34  30 30 36 35 30 34 43 60  VRWTF4534024810
    0010: 20 20 20 20 FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF      ............
    0020: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF  ................
```

Any ideas to get "**VRWTF4534024810**" from the sample text file?

***I am using Windows 10 64-bits OS

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In command line

```
for /f "tokens=1-26" %a in ('findstr 0000: input.txt') do @echo %r & set var=%r
```

or in script (double percent)

```
for /f "tokens=1-26" %%a in ('findstr 0000: input.txt') do @echo %%r & set var=%%r
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But can you explain this part `"tokens=1-26"` for me.
Thanks~

Comment: because loop iterator name %a 1-26 to map fields to %a ..%z (1-17,*) should work also, `for /?` for more details

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will give a better understanding for tokens and delims. :)
https://www.computing.net/howtos/show/batch-files-tokens-and-delimiters-for-loops/473.html